# Not reading the javascript file

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp, web

Below is my directory structure. My salesAdmin-AddRemoveClass.jsp (under WebContent) is trying to use and access salesAdmin-Modal.js but not being able to.

[image: Project Structure]

In my salesAdmin-AddRemoveClass, I have this line to point towards the javascript file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/WebContent/resource/js/salesAdmin-Modal.js"></script>
```

I don't know what is wrong with absolute path that I have given.

I'm new to web application world so forgive me if it's a silly mistake/question.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try a path that starts with /resource, i.e. /WebContent should not be included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/WebContent/resource/js/salesAdmin-Modal.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/resource/js/salesAdmin-Modal.js"></script>
```